# Return dictionary from mongodb, merge two fields values into single field as key value pairs?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Trying to merge two field values into single field as key value pairs.

Example documents:

```
{
    "_id":  ObjectId(""),
    "id":   "23",
    "name": "MyName"
}, 
    "_id":  ObjectId(""),
    "id":   "24",
    "name": "MyName2"
}
```

In this case, I want the output as: `{"23": "MyName", "24": "MyName2"}`
Is it possible to do this using only mongo and not programming language to iterate and work the data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

**Query :**

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{ $project: { _id: 0, idNameAsArray: { $split: [{ $concat: ["$id", ",", "$name"] }, ','] } } },
{ $group: { _id: '', arrayOfIdNameArrays: { $push: '$idNameAsArray' } } },
{ $project: { idNameObjs: { $arrayToObject: "$arrayOfIdNameArrays" } } },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$idNameObjs' } }])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e085452d3b84db1053c3c6e"),
    "id" : "23",
    "name" : "MyName"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e085452d3b84db1053c3c6f"),
    "id" : "24",
    "name" : "MyName2"
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "23" : "MyName",
    "24" : "MyName2"
}
```

**Ref :** [Aggregation-pipeline-operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)